# Antlr with compiler for CIL code

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr, cil

I'm doing a compiler for study purpose.

It uses **Antlr** tool targeted for c# code generation.

So far, i can handle the gramar. Lexical, Sintatic, my tests are ok.

My aim is to generate CIL bytecode, i'm kinda familiar with it.

The problem is...
I don't know a good way to "output" the code. I'd like some advice, example to generate it.

One thought i have, is to create a Class "compiler" with tons of method related to the node and call the method as the tree is iterated.

Ideia:

```
Class Compiler
{
   private AppededStrings = "";

   void CreateClass();
   void EndClass();
   void AddParam();
   void setAtributeToTheClass("public");
   ... and so on ...
}
```

Is this a good approach?
I could not find a topic talking specific about this.

Comment: @GuyCoder How will LLVM help you generate CIL?

Comment: @GuyCoder I'll check LLVM, but i'm not sure if it is what i'm looking for. I just need a good practice to "build" a lot of micro CIL corresponding to each semantic action.

Comment: I can't spend the time needed for a complete answer but this [ANTLR page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/LLVM) should help.

Comment: The short answer is to use StringTemplate, also from Terrence of ANTLR. The referenced page should serve as an example.

Comment: Anybody has some real example compiling for any virtual machine (java, cil, hypothetical)? I could not find a good example. It seems antlr is not well used or popular.

Comment: *"It seems antlr is not well used or popular."*, is that supposed to trigger an answer? :)

Comment: Yeah, but how it is my only option until now, i have no choice than gather all info i can before discard it completely and find another solution. =P

Comment: It's too bad ANTLR isn't that popular and used that often... Best of luck, of course!

Comment: Seems to be a problem in your link. @GuyCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from [ANTLR 3.x](http://www.antlr3.org/).

Once you have an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from ANTLR, per this question, the next task is to convert that into a set of executable instructions. Since the author is not requesting assembly as the output but [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and is working with ANTLR, the best example on the web comes from the author of ANTLR. On this [page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/LLVM) Ter talks about how one uses the [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) tool to generate the output that becomes the instructions. While Ter uses the popular [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) for his demonstration, the same concepts apply for generating CIL as the author request.

Another option.

When I worked with [Mercury,](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/) originally they generated CIL code. In the years that passed the CIL was not maintained but people still wanted to use Mercury with the .Net world. Since in the .NET world any .NET language compiles to CIL, by generating C# as the output of the Mercury compiler and then compiling the C# to CIL they achieved the same result of compiling Mercury to CIL but just via an intermediate language. Nowhere is it a rule that an intermediate language has to be a low level language.

Comment: Well, that is related for what i was looking for for antlr solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx will work for you :)

Comment: Nice material, i didn't know this one. So beautiful and nevertheless, helpful.